# How to use Buefy's Dialog component with user provided content and be safe in terms of XSS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, xss, buefy, html-sanitizing

Buefy's Dialog component expects a `message` prop - string. According to a documentation, that string can contain HTML. I would like to use template values in the string, but of course is should be XSS safe.

### Current unsafe example

This is unsafe, as `this.name` is unsafe. I could use a NPM package to html encode the name, but I really prefer to use Vue.

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    name: { type: String, required: false },
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
        title: 'myTitle',
        message: `<p>Hello ${this.name}</p>`, // unsafe - possible XSS!
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        confirmText: 'OK',
        type: 'is-success',
        onConfirm: async () => {
          // something
        },
      });
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

This is an issue of the used Buefy component, as documented [here](https://buefy.org/documentation/dialog#api-view):

[image]

### Desired Setup

I've created a new component, in this example I call it *ModalMessage.Vue*

```html
<template>
    <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
  },
});
</script>
```

Then I like to render the *ModalMessage.Vue* to a `string` in Typescript:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import ModalMessage from 'ModalMessage.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    name: { type: String, required: false },
  },
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
        title: 'myTitle',
        message:, // todo render ModalMessage and pass name prop
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        confirmText: 'OK',
        type: 'is-success',
        onConfirm: async () => {
          // something
        },
      });
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

#### Question

How could I render the ModalMessage.Vue, and passing the name prop, to a `string`?

I'm pretty sure this is possible - I have seen it in the past. Unfortunately I cannot find it on the web or StackOverflow. I could only find questions with rendering a template **from** string, but I don't need that - it needs to be **to** string.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64285043/381282) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho your real question is **"How to use Buefy's Dialog component with user provided content and be safe in terms of XSS"**

So what you want is to create some HTML, include some user provided content (`this.name`) within that HTML content and display it in a Dialog. You are right that putting unfiltered user input into a `message` parameter of `Dialog` is not safe (as clearly noted in [Buefy docs](https://buefy.org/documentation/dialog/#api-view))

But your "Desired Setup" seems unnecessary complicated. Imho the easiest way is to use (poorly documented) fact that `message` parameter of Buefy `Dialog` configuration objects can be an `Array` of VNode's instead of a string. It is poorly documented but it is very clear from the source [here](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/a725a02dc6158660f446912b41cb835b83047f51/src/components/dialog/Dialog.vue#L32) and [here](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/a725a02dc6158660f446912b41cb835b83047f51/src/components/dialog/index.js#L11) that if you pass an array of VNode's, Buefy puts that content into Dialogs default slot instead of rendering it using `v-html` (which is the dangerous part)

And easiest way to get `Array` of `VNode` in Vue is to use slots...

So the component:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
        title: 'myTitle',
        message: this.$slots.default, // <- this is important part
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        confirmText: 'OK',
        type: 'is-success',
        onConfirm: async () => {
          // something
        },
      });
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

and it's usage:

```html
<MyDialog>
  <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
</MyDialog>
```

or

```html
<MyDialog>
  <ModalMessage :name="name" />
</MyDialog>
```

In both cases if the `name` contains any HTML, it will be [encoded by Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-buefy-dialog-component-with-user-provided-data-lthkz) is a simple demo of the technique described above (using plain JS - not TS)

Comment: Cool! I think is was searching for this. Nevertheless, I'm sure (but indeed over complicated) that we could get the html string of a component. But maybe that should be in another stackoverflow question? Anyway will test this and mark as answer afterwards :)

Comment: Yes, you can render the component into a string - already [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64285043/381282) that. But it's really not necessary in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import ModalMessage from 'ModalMessage.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    name: { type: String, required: false },
  }, 
  methods: {
    showModal() {
      const message = new Vue({
        components: { ModalMessage },
        render: h => h('ModalMessage', { name: this.name })
      })
      message.$mount()

      const dialog = this.$buefy.dialog.confirm({
        title: 'myTitle',
        message: [message._vnode],
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        confirmText: 'OK',
        type: 'is-success',
        onConfirm: async () => {
          // something
        },
      });

      dialog.$on('hook:beforeDestroy', () => {
          message.$destroy()
      });
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Source code：

[image]

[image]

Demo:

[image]

Comment: But this is still unsafe? If `this.name` has a script, it's executed?

Comment: @Julian It's safe. I've made some adjustments and it's working right now.

Comment: a yes, but If I need more html tags in the template (this is a stripped version), then I need to call many times `h` isn't?

Comment: @Julian You can pass the content into a default slot of your component and then do `message: this.$slots.default`

Comment: yes. Or create a separate `.vue` file and create the instance. Like your `ModalMessage `. `const message = new Vue(ModalMessage)`